# How do I Download Consolidated Schedule of Investment Tables from a Company's 10-Q?

Tags: data

I need to analyze the Consolidated Schedule of Investment Tables found in the 10-Q of several companies. For example, from the following 10-Q report: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1655888/000095017021000801/orcci_10q_2021-06-30.htm#soi

I would need the tables from every page that has "Consolidated Schedule of Investments" at the top (in this case pg. 4-36).

I'm having trouble getting these tables into Excel or R for analysis. I've been researching and trying things but I'm honestly a bit over my head here being fairly new to programming.

Is there a place where I can download these tables or a way to access them through R or Excel?

Comment: Check out the links under "We Provide Data" section of SEC's web site.